# When using PDO statements, can I insert variables safely using functions?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have the following function which allows me to perform queries on the database (specified within the same class).

Do i need to use the `bind_param` function to safely escape these variables?

If not, how would I assign the variables passed into the function as the values to the keys?

```
public function query($dms, $col, $date, $ascDesc)
        {
            $this->stmt = $this->dbh->prepare("{$dms} {$col} FROM {$this->table} ORDER BY UNIX_TIMESTAMP({$date}) $ascDesc");
            $this->stmt->execute();
            return $this;
        }
```

Comment: You can't bind tables or column names... but you can bind the values: $col, $date and $ascDesc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that way you can use something like this (remember to bind just values, not arrays... in case for array use foreach and bind each value):

```
public function query($dms, $col, $date, $ascDesc)
    {
        $this->stmt = $this->dbh->prepare("{$dms} :col FROM {$this->table} ORDER BY UNIX_TIMESTAMP(:date) :ascDesc;");
        $this->stmt->bindParam(':col', $col, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $this->stmt->bindParam(':date', $date, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $this->stmt->bindParam(':ascDesc', $ascDesc, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $this->stmt->execute();
        return $this;
    }
```